# How to locate the right appActivity in mobile-automation?

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

For mobile application automation I am using appium and 3th app named:

> apkinfo

to locate package name and app activity.

i know the "package name" but i have an application that contains a lot of Activities

[image]

how to select the main/right activity ?

Answer (score 0):

U can always get current activity from adb shell
on the device -> Open the app that you want to use for automation/ the screen in the app that you want for automation 
on the commandprompt in pc  ->
1. Launch cmd
2. Enter adb shell by command -> `adb shell`
3. Enter the following command ->  `dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'`
4. get the current activity and use that

Answer (score 0):

You can get more details here [link](http://qahumor.blogspot.in/2016/01/appium-how-to-get-activity-name-of.html)

To do this , you can follow below steps

Step 1 : using the aapt command.

To get the **aapt.exe** , you have to navigate to ***android sdk folder*** then ***build-tools*** and goto some ***api version*** . for example(specific to my machine, change the path accordingly)

### E:\Android\adt\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W

open command prompt and run the below command

## - aapt dump badging

for example : Let's take whatsapp application

## - aapt dump badging E:\com.whatsapp.apk

output :

You can pick the launchable-activity which you can use in your automation .

After running the command you can get the package name and launchable-activity with few other details as highlighted in below :

[image]

You can try with your app too, to get the details of launchable activity.